# Auto Select Current week in DateRangePicker

Tags: daterangepicker

I used DateRange Picker In my HTMLTwig

Html:-

```
<input id="date-range14" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Select Your Week">
```

JavaScript :-

```
$('#date-range14').dateRangePicker({
            batchMode: 'week',
            showShortcuts: false,
            useCurrent: true,
            autoApply: true,
            weekStart: 0,
            autoUpdateInput: true,
            locale: {
                cancelLabel: 'Clear'
            }
        });
```

I Want Auto select Current Week Default.
Is there Any Solution ?

Answer (score 3):

[See this working demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohsin889/38ktj6qz/).

**Explanation:**

Use moment.js, below method will give you start date of current week

```
moment().startOf('isoWeek') //Monday is the week start day
moment().startOf('Week') //Sunday is the week start day
```

This configuration will auto select current week by default.

```
   $('#dtpFrom').daterangepicker({
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Week': [moment().startOf('isoWeek'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },
            "startDate": moment().startOf('isoWeek'),
            "endDate": moment()
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            //This is on date change event.
        });
```

You can also generate your custom configuration using [online daterangepicker's config generator](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config).

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra `span` tag and example js codes are below:
[Example I took from here:](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex3)

```js
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
    
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
```

Comment: no,not like that i want current week **29-jan,2017 - 4-feb,2017** and when i pick a date then default this week is selected.@Ruhul Amin